# Accessing directory of small files as one file

Tags: dataset, apache-hadoop

I have a job that results in a directory of part- files. I'd like to read it as if it were one file. Specifically, I'd like to read it that way over a web interface.

How can I do either one of these things? Is there a hadoop component which makes this easy?

Comment: Most Hadoop tools, including standard MapReduce and Spark, treat single file and directory with files the same way. E.g. if on HDFS you have files`/data/jobresult/part-00001`, `/data/jobresult/part-00002`, `/data/jobresult/part-00003`, etc., you can read them all from Spark using `sc.textFile("/data/jobresult")`. Note, that nested directories are not supported - only plain files or flat directories with such files.

Answer (score 1):

```
hadoop fs -getmerge <hdfs-output-directory> <local-file>
```

This command can be used to concatenate the HDFS files into a single local file.

Ref : http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getmerge